# Cannot view a json file explicitly from the server using URL its telling File not Found

Tags: asp.net, json, url, server, http-status-code-404

I have uploaded a manifest.json file in server for my asp.net project but I cannot view the content of the file when i explicitly call it using a URL whereas i can view the other files in the same directory such as the css and js files
Here is my manifest.json file code

```
{
  "name": "Example Foo",
  "short_name": "Example",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "../content/themes/img/logos/launcher-icon-0-75x.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 0.75
    },
    {
      "src": "../content/themes/img/logos/launcher-icon-1x.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 1.0
    },
    {
      "src": "../content/themes/img/logos/launcher-icon-1-5x.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 1.5
    },
    {
      "src": "../content/themes/img/logos/launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 2.0
    },
    {
      "src": "../content/themes/img/logos/launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 3.0
    },
    {
      "src": "../content/themes/img/logos/launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 4.0
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/home/index.cshtml",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "lang": "en"
}
```

I uploaded it in server. Now when i try to call it explicitly using url like www.example.com/manifest.json then its giving an error telling file not found whereas if i am calling it explicitly using localhost url like localhost:6453/manifest.json then i can see the content what should i do?

Comment: Its a live project in production...

Comment: Please provide some of your code, so that users can assist you :)

Comment: I have added the code to the question is it bit clear now?

Comment: Yes it's clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow `JSON` files in your `web.config`

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

You can check [this article](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config) for a more detailed explanation about how to add mime types.

In some cases this creates a conflict with the same mime map in the `applicationhost.config` file. If so, then you have to remove the `fileExtension` first, like this:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```